# sed: match pattern, and replace every occurence of a different pattern thereafter

Tags: text-processing, sed

Suppose I have `aaaaabaaaaa`, and assume that `a` can be an arbitrary pattern; likewise for `b`.

How do I pattern match for `aaaaaab`, then replace all the `aaaaa`'s after `b` with `b`'s, but none of the `a`'s prior to `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too complex in sed, but much easier in Perl:

```
perl -pe '/b/g and substr($_, pos) =~ s/a/A/g'
```

The first match `/b/g` matches the first `b` in the string which sets `pos` to its position. Then, the substring starting at that position undergoes the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

with only sed , but you must choose a sequence of characters you will never have in your data .

```
 ( echo 'zzzaaaaadddd' ; 
   echo 'ssssaaaaajaaaaakaaaaa'; 
   echo 'ssssaaaaaaaaaakaaaaa';  ) | \
      sed '/aaaaa.*aaaaa/ { s/aaaaa/_=|=_/; s/aaaaa/GGGGG/g; s/_=|=_/aaaaa/ }'

zzzaaaaadddd
ssssaaaaajGGGGGkGGGGG
ssssaaaaaGGGGGkGGGGG
```

**explanation :**

- line with at least 2 times aaaaa will be affected
- substitute **aaaaa** with a string `_=|=_` you will never have
- substitute others **aaaaa** with waht you want **GGGGG**
- substitute back `_=|=_` with **aaaaa**

Answer (score 1):

Try also this recursive `sed` solution:

```
sed ':L; s/\(a*\)b\(a*\)a/\1b\2b/; tL; ' file
```

It recursively replaces every target `a` occurrence with `b` until all are done.